# Number of ways to distribute keys among the cabinet members according to given condition

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

There is a cabinet consisting of m members. Cabinet materials are stored in safe. How many lock should the safe have, and how many keys should be made for these locks, and how these keys have to be distributed among the cabinet members such that the safe can be open if and only if at least j members of the cabinet are present?

Attempt: Should I approach this by Stirling numbers of second kind. Where first I have to find the number of locks, then distribute in S(n,k) ways where n is the number of locks and k is the number of keys. Still I am unable to justify?

Comment: The question earlier question has an artificial limit of $30$ on $m$, but it doesn’t enter into the answer. You will also find answers to the general question at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342001/combinatorics-riddle-keys-and-a-safe) and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581461/what-is-the-minimum-number-of-locks-on-the-cabinet-that-would-satisfy-these-cond), even though the actual questions contained specific numbers.

Comment: Sorry didn't know that.

Comment: That’s okay; the search feature isn’t all that easy to use. I just remembered having seen similar problems, and enough about them to be able to locate a few.