# keys and locks of a safe

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-game-theory

A company manager bought a new safe and want out of his 11 employees only a group of 6 together to be able to open it, so he decided to put more than one lock on the safe and give each emplyee an amount of keys to part of the locks, what's the least amount of keys and locks possible to achieve the manager goal?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Maybe this question will solve your [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/342001/415941).

Comment: One trivial solution would be to put 6 locks and give one key to each employee, I guess.
Do you require that any subset of 6 employees must be able to open the safe ?

Comment: @Yoël yes, any subset of 6 employees.