# A really cool combinatorics problem / puzzle

Tags: combinatorics

Problem statement

> 6 scientists are working on a secret project. They wish to lock up the documents in a cabinet so that cabinet can be opened when and only when 3 or more scientists are present. What is smallest number of locks needed? What is smallest number of keys each scientist must carry??

Let $n$ be the number of locks. Let us name each scientist as $1,2,3,4,5,6$.Let $S_i$ be the set of keys that scientist $i$ is carrying and each scientist carries $k$ number of keys.we would get following results

> $|S_i|=k$
>
> $|S_p \cup S_q \cup S_r|=n$
>
> $n=3k-(|S_p \cap S_q|+|S_p \cap S_r|+|S_r \cap S_q|)+|S_p \cap S_q \cap S_r|$

I tried manipulating the above results in hope of finding solutions but failed.Is there anything I am missing or is this approach entirely wrong?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342001/combinatorics-riddle-keys-and-a-safe)

Comment: You have made the mistake of jumping in at the deep end when you don't know how to swim. Start by paddling at the shallow end - ie put some small numbers in and explore what happens - eg when there are 2 locks and 3 scientists.