# Is there a way of constructing a set of sets such that any union of $m$ subsets is the alphabet?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose the following problem:
Given a number $N$ and $m<N$, define the minimum-size alphabet $\mathcal{A}$ that enables the construction of a set $\mathscr{N}$ consisting of $N$ subsets such that:

- There is no union of $i$ subsets of $\mathscr{N}$ whose union is able to span the entire alphabet for any $i<m$.
- Every union of $j$ subsets of $\mathscr{N}$ is able to span the entire alphabet.

By "spanning the entire alphabet" it is meant that the union contains *at least one* copy of every element of the alphabet. The problem consists on finding the alphabet and constructing the set $\mathscr{N}$.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are asking, but I expect that [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342001/combinatorics-riddle-keys-and-a-safe) is a duplicate.  Note that the linked question is also requiring that no smaller unions can cover the set (a constraint you omitted but which I suspect you intended).  Note too that this has nothing at all to do with set theory.

Comment: Thank you, I was precisely writing this constraint now, and I did not know exactly which topic this problem would fit. However, different from the linked question, I am not interested in knowing how many "locks" are necessary, but how to build the set of sub-sets.

Comment: "The subsets can have repeated elements."  Then why put in the restriction that the subsets need to be the same size?  Just let them be any size and the just add repeated elements to make the all the same size.

Comment: @fleablood edited. Thank you.

Comment: $N = 0$ is impossible and $N=1$ is the trivial solutions.  If $m=1$ then we must have every set be the entire alphabet also the trivial solution.  (Do the sets themselves need to be distinct? I see no reason that should be a requirement.)  So we can assume $N\in [2,10]$ and $m\in [2,N]$.

Comment: @fleablood they must be distinct because of the requirement regardind $i$. Assume that two sets are identical. Then, pick another $m-2$ sets and the union of all these must be the alphabet. Removing one of the identical sets from this set will also result in the whole alphabet, however we would be using $m-1$ sets for this, and this is not allowed.

Comment: @embedded_dev is the value of 10 special? I prefer to work on problems that are not just a "finite check" in nature. so im wondering if you can generalize "10" to "an arbitrary positive integer $n$ (with $n \ge 10$ if you like)?

Comment: @mathworker21 I would not mind that, there is nothing special with this value. I just want to be able to understand the idea on this problem, combinatorics is always complicated to me.

Comment: For $m=2$ just make sure no element is missing in more than $m-1=1$ set e.g. for $N=5$: $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, $\{0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, $\{0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, $\{0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, $\{0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9\}$. For $m=3$ just make sure no element is missing in more than $m-1=2$ sets e.g. for $N=5$: $\{1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9\}$, $\{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, $\{0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, $\{0,1,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, $\{0,1,2,5,6,7,8,9\}$. And so on...

Comment: -1 The question is still rather unclear, but due to the bounty I cannot vote to close. My best guess is currently that you are asking, for a general finite alphabet $\mathcal{A}$, the following:

Given integers $N$ and $m$ such that $0<m<N\leq|\mathcal{A}|$, construct a collection $\mathcal{S}$ of subsets of $\mathcal{A}$ with $|\mathcal{S}|=N$, such that for every subset $\mathcal{T}\subset\mathcal{S}$ you have
$$\bigcup\mathcal{T}=\mathcal{A}\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad|\mathcal{T}|\geq m.$$

Comment: @Servaes I hope that the question is clearer now. I will soon edit the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've come to a solution which is roughly stated in some other questions in this website, but not very well explained and it took me a while to understand it, so I will provide a general explanation here.

Given $N$ and $m$, the first thing to be determined is the size of the alphabet. In fact, the whole problem follows once the alphabet is constructed and the main problem here is to how actually construct the alphabet instead of the set of subsets. To help understand the solution, define $\mathcal{N}$ a set of $N$ distinct elements.

Given the consideration that no union of $i$ subsets must result in the entire alphabet for $i<m$, we can build the alphabet such that each element of is "not reachable" by a given union of $i$ subsets. That is, for every possible union of $i$ subsets, there is one specific member of the alphabet that is not present. Evidently, the way to achieve the minimal alphabet that follows this rule is by setting $i=m-1$. This means that we shall pick all of the possible $i$ combinations of elements of $\mathcal{N}$, and each of them will be associated with an element of the alphabet (the element that this subset doesn't contain). This means that there exists an univoque map of each number between $0$ and $N$ of the alphabet to a subset of $m-1$.

This subset in turn will allow us to determine each set that is part of the set of size $N$ we are building. Iterating from $n = 0$ to $N$, on the $n$th member of the set: check the alphabet for all the elements that are associated with a combination containing $n$. $n$ will consist of all the elements of the alphabet that do not map to a combination containing $n$.

Example:
$N=4$,$m=2$.
$\mathcal{N} = (a,b,c,d)$ and $i=1$. The possible combinations of one element of the elements of $\mathcal{N}$ are: $a,b,c,d$. This will be the alphabet (consists of $4$ elements in this case). As we can see, element $1$ maps to $a$, element $2$ maps to $b$... and so on. The subsets are built on the following way: Each of the subsets consist of the elements that are not mapped by each element of $\mathcal{N}$. So on the first case, the element $1$ doesn't map to $b$,$c$ nor $d$. This means that the first subset will be $(b,c,d)$. Conversely, our final set will be:
$$\big[(b,c,d),(a,c,d),(a,b,d),(a,b,c)\big]$$

Comment: What is your unique map from the alphabet to subsets of $m-1$, for each number between $0$ and $N$? What are subsets of $m-1$ even? And your question asks to construct a set $\mathcal{N}$ *given* an alphabet and $N$ and $m$. Yet your answer constructs an alphabet from $N$ and $m$. Could you please clarify what you are asking, and what you are doing in this answer?

Comment: The question was ill posed by me with regard to the alphabet being given. I will edit to try to make it clearer.

Comment: Why raise a bounty for drawing attention and then accept your own answer?
Nothing in the system is going to refund you the 200 points anyway.

Comment: @HandeBruijn I don't care about reputation, I came up with the answer two days after starting the bounty so I posted it. I'm not interested in "refunding" imaginary points.